# Rails 4 ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am learning rails advanced search through a tutorial where user can find posts based on the category. But somehow my advanced page is giving me this error:

> ArgumentError in Searches#new Showing
>   app/views/searches/new.html.haml where line #10
>   raised:
>
> wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)

The line on which I get the error is:

```
= s.text_field :category, options_for_select(@categories), :include_blank => true
```

The above file is new.html.haml (Line 10). Here is the searches controller.rb, 
I think the `@categories` in the `new` method is not right.

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @search = Search.new
        @categories = Idea.uniq.pluck(:category)
    end

    def create
        @search = Search.create(search_params)
        redirect_to @search 
    end

    def show
        @search = Search.find(params[:idea_id])
    end

    private

    def search_params
        params.require(:search).permit(:keywords, :category)
    end

end
```

And my model.rb

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

    def search_ideas
        ideas = Idea.all

        ideas = ideas.where(["title LIKE ?","%#{keywords}%"]) if keywords.present?
        ideas = ideas.where(["category LIKE ?","%#{category}%"]) if category.present?

        return ideas
    end

end
```

I tried to use `collection_select` instead of `s.text_field`but it still gives me this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `s.select` like this:

```
= s.select :category, options_for_select(@categories), :include_blank => true
```

Answer (score 1):

Let refer to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) first.

> select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)

Because it has TWO hash options, so you need to specify the `options` before `html_options`

```
s.select :category, options_for_select(@categories), {}, {include_blank: true}
```